# Jmeter showing error while reading data from csv file, I've try all possible steps but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am trying to login multiple user from csv file but jMeter showing error.

**[image: Error in Sampler Result tab]**

Thread Name:Thread Group 1-3
Sample Start:2020-07-23 02:22:14 PKT
Load time:666
Connect Time:285
Latency:666
Size in bytes:677
Sent bytes:346
Headers size in bytes:414
Body size in bytes:263
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:400
Response message:Bad Request

**Error in (Response body tab)**

"{"errors":{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0."]},"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"detail":"Please refer to the errors property for additional details.","instance":"/api/Login"}"

**Error in (Response data tab)**
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 263
Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:1a585b00-9997-43ca-96bb-6f28ed4b25ea
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=bfa7c426b598232c8e6a1a614f8550c9cd24377eaa1f91d7bbbac45fb7a32623;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=clearmotsqaapiidentity.azurewebsites.net
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 21:22:16 GMT

Comment: Did you save file as CSV?

Comment: Yes, save as CSV format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot help unless we see:

1. Textual representation of your CSV file (i.e. opened in [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Notepad) or other text editor)
2. Your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup

In addition it would be nice to see:

- "Request" tab of the View Results Tree listener
- [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) showing available [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

My expectation is that you need to use the correct delimiter or set "Allow quoted data" to `True`